# 此方では　関数型プログラミングにも、 対応されて　いますよね？

Tags: サポート, 話題の範囲

伺います、

此方では　関数型プログラミングにも、
対応されて　いますよね？
"

例えば、

LISP、Forth、エクセル関数、
等です。
"

質問具体例は、

1〜10万5千以上に　達する、
連番の　生成を、
マクロを　用いず、
エクセルの　関数のみで、
行う。
"

一覧中に、

重複出現する　テキストの、
重複を　省き、
リスト化する。
"

但し、

エクセルマクロは　用いず、
関数のみで　行う。
"

エクセルの、

関数において、
配列数式の　要素を、
複数　後から、
連結する。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

はい、話題としては範囲の中です。そのものずばりなタグがついた質問たちが存在することをご確認ください: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags。たとえば [lisp](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp)、[forth](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth)、[excel](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) あたりです。

（Forth やエクセルの関数が関数型プログラミングと関係が強いかは別の問題として存在しますが、どちらにせよプログラミングなのでオントピックではあります。）

Comment: 有り難うございます。所で、タグexcelは　VBA用ではないのですか？

Comment: VBA には VBA 用のタグが存在します https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba

Comment: VBAに関する質問であればタグも [vba] を使えばよいですが、nouble さんがこの質問で例題として挙げたのが「マクロを使わないで」と条件付けしてるので [excel] を回答したのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 有り難うございます、左様なのですね。